# Optic fiber with partial diffusion

Tags: led, optical-fibre

I've seen a partially diffusing flexible optic fiber used in several places, but I can't figure out what exactly to google to find the stuff. Does it have a name?

I'd like to stick leds to each end of a ~50cm piece of it, and have it light up all the way.

Comment: Unfortunately shopping questions are off-topic, as per the [help centre](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I edited the question, hopefully it's ok now.

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept your answer. This will keep it from popping back to the front page of the site looking for more answers.

Comment: @ThePhoton thank you! I'd completely forgotten about this.

Comment: Can you add an image of the same?? otherwise, it's hard to keep guessing from the general description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to be [side glow fiber](https://www.google.fi/search?q=side%20glow%20fiber&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=1ewXVLfCKcbmyQOHyoH4Bg&ved=0CB8QsAQ&biw=1600&bih=799).